# Re-run last command by first characters using Spyder history

Tags: spyder

In the Spyder console, is it possible to re-run a command by calling it with its first characters? I am thinking of something like

```
!run
```

to run the last `run` command  or

```
!print
```

to run the last `print` command.

Answer (score 1):

(Spyder maintainer here) There's no such functionality in Spyder, sorry.

However, you can write the first characters of a previous command (e.g. `run`) and use the Up and Down arrow keys to move among the history of all commands that start with those characters.

Comment: That's very useful! Thanks!